# psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) el valor null para la columna «name» viola la restricción not null

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create users for my blog, but when I try the functionality of the code, does it give me an error, can someone help me?

```
Error MSG

(psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) el valor null para la columna «name» viola la restricción not null
```

```
models,py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_user'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

```
def show_signup_form():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('public.index'))
    form = SignupForm()
    error = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
# Comprobamos que no hay ya un usuario con ese email o nombre
        user = User.get_by_email(email)
        name = User.get_by_name(name)
        
        if user is not None:
            error = f'El email {email} ya está siendo utilizado por otro usuario'
        elif name is not None:
            error = f'El Nombre de Invocador {name} ya está siendo utilizado por otro usuario si crees que se trata de un plagio contactate con nosotros'

 # Creamos el usuario y lo guardamos
  user = User(name=name, email=email,region=region, mainl=mainl, main2=main2)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            # Enviamos un email de bienvenida
            send_email(subject='Bienvenid@ al U-ProTeam',
                       sender=current_app.config['DONT_REPLY_FROM_EMAIL'],
                       recipients=[email, ],
                       text_body=f'Hola {name}, bienvenid@ a U-ProTeam',
                       html_body=f'<p>Hola <strong>{name}</strong>, bienvenid@ a U-ProTeam</p>')
            # Dejamos al usuario logueado
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            next_page = request.args.get('next', None)
```

```
class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Nombre de Invocador', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField('Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
```

I don't understand why the error if the rest of the fields accept data without problems.
also when I remove the null the user saves me with the name null and it does not help me for the development of the rest of my code

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code where you populate and save a new user.

Comment: ready and modify as requested

Comment: You reassign `name = User.get_by_name(name)` before creating the `User`.  Assign it to a different variable like `check_name = User.get_by_name(name)` and test `check_name is not None` a couple of lines below.

Answer (score 0):

thanks I already found the error was that I had double referenced name and that is why it did not save the name since it made a query to the DB that threw me the name = null result